# Can I use the Audited annotation of Hibernate Envers without including the whole Hibernate distribution?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, hibernate-envers

In a client-server-based enterprise project I am using Hibernate with Envers. The client developers want to have a shared library that contains all entities so that they can use them in their client development without including any server-side dependencies. As these entities are annotated with the @Audited annotation the client library will contain the Envers dependency which is acceptable.

However, Envers itself contains all kinds of dependencies: hibernate-core, hibernate-jpa-api, javassist and many more any they will also be included.

Is there a way to only include the annotation in my library without actually including the whole server-side stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It would ultimately depending on the context of *client* in this case.

But assuming your client uses some protocol to talk to your server side backend, you could package the `org.hibernate.envers` annotations in a separate artifact that you include with your client deployment, just like I suspect you're doing with the JPA annotations.

The only care you must be mindful of is that as you upgrade the `hibernate-envers` artifact, you'll need to repackage that special jar artifact to take into account any annotation changes.

I know users have requested being able to configure Envers via XML mappings.  The hope and goal is to try and include this as a part of `orm.xml` configuration in Hibernate 7.

Answer (score 0):

In the final solution I ended up including the "hibernate-envers" dependency in my Maven pom.xml. Below the dependency declaration I am using a bunch of "exclude" tags in order to exclude those dependencies that are critical only when actually running Hibernate but not critical when only using the annotations and maybe validating entities. By that I was able to use all Hibernate annotations (not only @Audited) but still keep the footprint relatively small.
I started with @Naros ' approach first (thanks for the suggestion) but that lead me to including more and more source code dependencies that were required by various Hibernate annotations. Of course it depends what you want to achieve but for me personally the Maven-based solution has worked better. Here's the POM that is working for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
                <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    hibernate-commons-annotations
                </artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```